# Hiding navigation bar/status bar/prompt

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get rid of the white bar at the top of my app.
http://cl.ly/image/3Z2I1x0H3H17

I am currently using a navigation controller as the root view. I've also tried just having a UIViewController as the root view.

In the first UIViewController I have tried:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

This does nothing.

I have also tried:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
  return YES;
}
```

Which hides the status icons (battery, cell connection indicator).

But really, I just want all that white space gone.

Comment: I ended up getting [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; to work. I'm not sure why it wasn't working before. Sorry, none of the answers here fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Or set Status Bar to 'None' in the XIB.

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad add this code:

```
//checks if device is running iOS 7 (or newer) or iOS 6 (or older)
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
     [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
} else {
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```

Then add this method:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```